# Error adding datasource to gridview winform

Tags: c#, mysql, database, datasource

I want to create a PivotGridControl and when I add new data source connection,after following the normal wizard procedure I got this:

[image]

[image]

Any Idea why this error prompted? I'm using MySQL connector.

Comment: Can you please post your **gridview design** and the **dataset code** you are passing to the **gridview**

Comment: First of all, is it a GridView, which is an ASP.NET server control, or a DataGridView, which is a WinForms control?

Comment: Please refer to this **[link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b028382e-faa9-4a2a-92f4-a4b53397e915/getting-error-when-trying-to-adding-a-data-souce?forum=sqldataaccess)** and do as per the solution provided there..!!

Comment: I have edited the question for more details.

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian I already refer to the solution provided there, but i'm new here and I don't have any idea what is it all about. Can you please guide me more?

Comment: @Ren you have to refresh your connection String

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian sorry,but how is that possible?can you please guide me?